# when click on next button at the same time active next li

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

```
<ul class="steps">
<li class="ms-hover active">1<li>
<li class="ms-hover">2<li>
<li class="ms-hover">3<li>
<li class="ms-hover">4<li>
<ul>

<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default button-next">Next</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default button-prev">Back</a>
```

how to active next li... ?

```
$(".button-next").click(function(){
    var $next;
    var $selected = $(".steps");
    $next = $selected.next('li');

    $next = $selected.next('li');
    $selected.removeClass("active");
    $next.addClass('active');
    $(".button-prev").show();
});
```

above coding not active next li... 
please help to me

Comment: `var $selected = $(".steps");` should be `$("#steps")`

Comment: @IgnacioAra thank bro..

Comment: @IgnacioAra `var $selected = $(".steps");` should actually be    `var $selected = $(".active");`

Comment: @Pete As you can see before the edition it was an `id` instead of a `class` https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49978878/revisions

Comment: @IgnacioAra still selects the wrong element though for OP code to work

Comment: @pete i had already menu bar with ul.. when i use $(".active") at the same time effects on menu bar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) instead of `.next()` to target the `<li>` with `active` class.

Then use `.next()` to target immediately following sibling

```
//Target active li  
$next = $selected.find('li.active');    
$next.removeClass("active");

//target next sibling of active
$next.next('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should close `<li>` and `<ul>` with `</li>` and `</ul>`.

From your original code, `$selected = $(".steps");` would select the `<ul>`, and `$selected.next('li')` would find the next `<li>` **sibling** which in this case is **nothing**.

```
$(".button-next").click(function(){
    var $next;
    var $selected = $(".steps");
    $next = $selected.next('li');

    $next = $selected.next('li');
    $selected.removeClass("active");
    $next.addClass('active');
    $(".button-prev").show();
});
```

You can replace `$(".steps");` with `$(".active");` to select the `<li>` with class `active`. And find the next `<li>` with `$next = $selected.next('li');` like the following code:

```
$(".button-next").click(function(){
    var $next;
    var $selected = $(".active");
    $next = $selected.next('li');
    $selected.removeClass("active");
    $next.addClass('active');
    $(".button-prev").show();
});
```

If the last `<li>` has class `active`, and you click the next button, it would remove all the `active` class and there's no next `<li>` anymore, so I made the following version to overcome this issue:

```js
$(".button-next").click(function() {
  // find the index of active li
  var index = $('.active').index('.ms-hover')
  var $li = $('.ms-hover')
  // remove all active class
  $li.removeClass('active')
  // find the next li and add active class
  $li.eq( (index+1) % $li.length ).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="steps">
  <li class="ms-hover active">1
  </li>
  <li class="ms-hover">2
  </li>
  <li class="ms-hover">3
  </li>
  <li class="ms-hover">4
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default button-next">Next</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default button-prev">Back</a>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i had already menu bar with ul.. with class "active"

Comment: when i use .active at the same time effects on menu bar.. that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you

```
$(".button-next").click(function(){
var $next;
// this line will find li with class active
var $selected = $("#steps").find("li.active");
//This line will select next li item 
$next = $selected.next('li');

$selected.removeClass("active");
// and class will be added to next element
$next.addClass('active');
$(".button-prev").show();
```

});

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.